# Why is ,,b = 1,2,3 parsed as (',b', '=', '1,2,3') in IPython?

Tags: python, ipython

I've noticed that IPython has some very strange parsing behaving for syntax that isn't legal Python.

```
In [1]: ,,b = 1,2,3
Out[1]: (',b', '=', '1,2,3')
```

There's something similar going on with semicolons, but it's not splitting into a tuple.

```
In [4]: ;;foo = 1;2;3
Out[4]: ';foo = 1;2;3'
```

Whilst it looks like `;` means the rest of the line is treated as a literal string, this isn't always the case:

```
In [5]: ,foo
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-f2137ad20ab5> in <module>()
----> 1 foo("")

NameError: name 'foo' is not defined

In [6]: ;foo
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-f2137ad20ab5> in <module>()
----> 1 foo("")

NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

Why does IPython do this? Is this documented or configurable?

Answer (score 8):

It's a convenience method for forcing the quotation, see the docs: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/reference.html#automatic-parentheses-and-quotes

From the docs:

> You can force automatic quoting of a function’s arguments by using ,
>   or ; as the first character of a line. For example:

```
In [1]: ,my_function /home/me  # becomes my_function("/home/me")
```

> If
>   you use ‘;’ the whole argument is quoted as a single string, while ‘,’
>   splits on whitespace:

```
In [2]: ,my_function a b c    # becomes my_function("a","b","c")
In [3]: ;my_function a b c    # becomes my_function("a b c")
```

> Note that
>   the ‘,’ or ‘;’ MUST be the first character on the line! This won’t
>   work:

```
In [4]: x = ,my_function /home/me # syntax error
```

For example just `;` outputs an empty string:

```
In [260]:

;
Out[260]:
''
```

As does just a comma `,`:

```
In [261]:

,
Out[261]:
''
```

I can't see anywhere that allows you to override this, I may be wrong but it looks like something that is hard coded in.

**EDIT**

OK I found a [mail](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/ipython-dev/2014-March/013639.html) post about this, you can turn it off by adding (or creating if it doesn't exist) the following to `.ipython/profile_default/static/custom/custom.js`, this is untested:

```
if (IPython.CodeCell) {
    IPython.CodeCell.options_default.cm_config.autoCloseBrackets = false;
}
```

Regarding your last point about why `,,b = 1,2,3` is being treated differently it looks like the white space is introducing some kind of break which then turns this into a tuple:

```
In [9]:

,,b =

Out[9]:
(',b', '=')
```

compare with no spaces:

```
In [10]:

,,b=
Out[10]:
',b='
```

Comment: I think the JS is for browsers only (I would be extremely surprised if IPython were running JavaScript code at the commandline).

Comment: @nneonneo that is true, I'll try and dig for one for the terminal IPython

Comment: Thanks, this explains the `,foo` and `;foo` but I don't see why `,,b` is treated differently and not as a function call.

Comment: Are you asking specifically about `,,b = 1,2,3`? It looks like that the white space after the b is causing it to turn into a tuple for instance `,,b=1,2,3` will output the entire statement as a string

Comment: @WilfredHughes I think it's trying to make a function call and getting confused because it only expects one leading comma, not two.